# Page Reload on button click in Framework 7 v2

Tags: cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am unable to reload a page on a button click. Actually, I have a page where a list of users is displayed. when I click on the delete button of a particular user a user is deleted and the list gets updated. I want to reload the same page as soon as we press delete button, to get the updated list of users.

I am using framework 7 v2 in my project.

Below mentioned is the function on click of the delete button, that is not working.

```
function delete_user(id)
{
     mainView.router.load({                   
                url: "/user_list/",
                ignoreChache: true,
                reload: true                    
            });
}
```

Comment: `I want to reload the same page as soon as we press delete button, to get the updated list of users.` - Without seeing any of the code, overall, to reload just the list you can use Ajax or try `location.reload()` ones the delete action has been processed.

Comment: location.reload() doesnt work in framework7.

Comment: You tagged JavaScript and even jQuery in your question,so I assumed you are able to run basic JavaScript or jQuery in your code.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that. Updated the tag list now. Anyways thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reload your page with `reloadCurrent` [router's option](http://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#route-options)

Ex : 
`yourView.router.navigate('urlPage', {reloadCurrent: true} );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `yourView.router.refreshPage()`. Has the same result.
See the [router documentation](https://framework7.io/docs/view.html), **Router Methods**